# onclick function can't work when click submit button

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, joomla2.5

I am using joomla for web app. In form page I want to click submit button to save in this database and insert to other database by get value in inputbox.Now I make function for get value in textbox and insert into database.I use function in onclick but it can't work.

This is my code >>

```
<?php

<form id="additem" action="" method="post" class="form-validate">


 ///////area for field box ////////

        <div>
            <button name="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="insert();" class="validate"><?php echo JText::_('Save');?></button>

            <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_stationery" />
            <input type="hidden" name="task" value="item.save"  />

            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo JRoute::_('/stationery/index.php/add-items');?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('JCANCEL');?>"><?php echo JText::_('JCANCEL');?></a>
            <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token');?>

        </div>
    </form>
<script>
function insert()
{
          <?php

    $form = $_POST['jform'];
    $name = $form['name'];
    $qty = $form['quantity'];
    $unit = $form['unit'];
    $cid = $form['category_id'];
    $db=&JFactory::getDbo();
    $user=&JFactory::getUser();
    $userid=$user->get('id');
    $query="INSERT INTO #__stationery_transactions (name,quantity,unit,category_id,status,created_time,created_user_id) VALUES ('$name','$qty','$unit','$cid','IN',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'$userid')";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->query();   
    ?>    }

</script>

    </div>

</body>
```

When I remove 2 lines >>

```
       <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_stationery" />
       <input type="hidden" name="task" value="item.save"  />
```

Onclick can use normally it can insert to database but this form can't save.

And If have 2 lines It can save this form but cannot use onclick.

Comment: `insert` will not execute php from javascript (it will be executed on page load). You need to use Ajax.

Comment: You should also stick to Joomla coding standards and create a proper module or components. There is documentation on this